# Visual Studio 2012 and 2015, Add > New Item > Reporting > Crystal File Report Not Found

Tags: c#, asp.net, crystal-reports

I have install "CRforVS_13_0_18" and "CRforVS_13_0_23" but both not works with VS 12 and VS 15. I add all References, see the image.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1F4nZIcL2xWECTIxsV0_wdmWh69l0_83I/view?usp=sharing
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1NjE_7yOfwmnvq5vwU_BPeU7S_n9INB-7/view?usp=sharing

Application type will be Windows Forms and Web Application Both.

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed the runtime as well ? unistall what you have, then install it again and get the runtime your app needs from this [page](https://wiki.scn.sap.com/wiki/display/BOBJ/Crystal+Reports%2C+Developer+for+Visual+Studio+Downloads).